# What is the recipe for the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction for correct simulation with the Oregonator model?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics

For a school project I'm trying to model the Oregonator and perform some experiments with the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction. Like predicting the reaction and the swings in concentrations. For that it is of course crucial that I perform the correct BZ-reaction, the reaction where the Oregonator is based on.

In the paper ['An Analysis of the Belousov-Zhabotinskii Reaction' by Casey Gray](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/rhumj/vol3/iss1/1/) I found a mathematical analysis of the Oregonator. For the experiment at school I want to perform the experiment exactly as described in the images below (the images are from the same paper).

Now I have a problem, because there are many different recipes on the internet, all a bit different. I am no experienced scientist, so I have difficulty determining which recipe I should use. So my question is: what is the exact recipe I should use for the (below) BZ-reaction? Which concentrations, how much of them and in what order I should add them (and any additional things that I should do).

Second, are the ingredients used in the BZ-reaction common in most laboratories? I need to perform the experiment at school; what are the chances they have those ingredients? And if school does not have some of chemicals, are they expensive?

Third, is ferroin the best (visual) indicator for the BZ-reaction? Is ferroin expensive (to make)? Are there alternatives that visually indicate the changes in concentrations?

**Description of BZ:**
[image]

**FKN mechanism:**
[image]

**An the Oregonator model (based on the FKN):**
[image]

**CORRECTION:** HBrO2 is not hypobromous acid, but bromous acid.

Comment: Link to paper links to image.

Comment: Label error: HBrO2 is Bromous acid and HBrO is Hypobromous acid. By the way, a simple oscillating system is H2O2 + HCl. More colorful perhaps, use HBr.

Comment: An experimental procedure for one variant of the B-Z reaction is here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34442/79678. You **really** should check if your school, *during the present global situation*, has the chemicals you need or would give *any priority at all* to ordering ones they do not have. And you need to fix the link, as @RodrigodeAzevedo commented.

Comment: To emphasize Ed's point - (1) All chemicals are expensive. This is not the same as buying table salt at the grocery store. (2) It is not just chemical cost but shipping too. Solids are generally easy to ship, but sulfuric acid has to be a freight truck shipment. (3) For such a complicated series of reactions you'll probably need "good" quality reagents to not have some contaminate that poisons the cycle.

Comment: I second what @MaxW commented and have one last comment. Once you commit to one of the variant published protocols, you will know what reagents and apparatus you will require. Then you need enough reagent to do the experiment multiple times because complicated experiments often do not work correctly the first or second time. As well, your school’s laboratory facility has to be open and a supervisor needs to be present. So I wish you success with this ambitious project, but please do not underestimate the time and effort required to achieve that success!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I fixed the link, thanks!

Comment: @AJKOER thank you for pointing that out. I can't change the image, because they're from the mentioned paper, but I've corrected the question.

Comment: @EdV thanks for the link to that experimental procedure. In your expert opinion, do you think that a simulation with the Oregonator is realistic if I perform the procedure like described in that post? Second, I checked with my school if they have all the chemicals. They do not have sodiumbromate (I now asked if they have potassium bromate) and ferroin, but the person I e-mailed assumed that school could order some. I'm waiting for the final decision.

Comment: @MaxW thank you for letting me realise these things. I indeed did not think of all those measures that need to be taken for transporting chemicals. Luckily my school has sulphuric acid (I thought that was a common chemical, but probably not regarding the risks). As far as I know, most of the chemicals come from Sigma Aldrich. What are your experiences with Sigma Aldrich?

Comment: @EdV I'll make sure that has enough reagent, provided that they can order the missing ones. I did not know that most complex experiments fail the first or second time, so I'll certainly keep that in mind.

Comment: I am not an expert on the B-Z experiment or computationally simulating it, though I have seen the experiment demonstrated by an actual expert (Prof. Irving Epstein of Brandeis U.). The reaction is very visually compelling, so if it was me, I would focus on getting that to work. Anyway, the key to success is often dogged perseverance and paying meticulous attention to details. Easier said than done! Good luck!